# Python requests on IPv6 only server does not seem to work

Tags: python, python-requests, ipv6

I have an IPv6 only Debian server, with python2.7 and `requests` installed. I follow the tutorial and do:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(110, 'Connection timed out'))
```

How do I make this work on an IPv6 server? It seems to work fine on my home machine (debian+py2.7+requests)

Comment: `api.github.com` has no IPv6 address. Have you tried a site that does have an IPv6 address?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No I havent, but the sites I want to download do not have IPV6 address I presume - what would be the work around on such machines?

Comment: [How do i reach IPv4 addresses from an IPv6-only network?](//serverfault.com/q/596616)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks! Do you think I can add these public google DNS64's as described here? https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/dns64 I am on a VPS box and I wonder if making changes to resolver conf will work.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I will try it now - thanks anyway! please put the link as the answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, that would not make a good answer. I'm no expert in network configurations, which is why I only used comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Actually, that dosent work

Comment: @JohnJ Whether it will work depends on your hosting provider. The part of the documentation to pay attention to is this: Google Public DNS64 is intended for use only on networks with access to a NAT64 gateway using the reserved NAT64 prefix `64:ff9b::/96`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You complain bitterly to GitHub regarding their *still* not having deployed IPv6, despite many people asking them for this for several years.

Some people have put up public IPv6 proxies to GitHub, though for your safety and mine I won't recommend any particular one. It's also possible to do this yourself.

Ultimately, GitHub needs to join the rest of us in the 21st century. It should not be necessary for the community to provide a service that GitHub themselves are expected to be providing!

Comment: TBH I dont care about github, I am just trying to download pages and it does not seem to work on my IPV6 only machine.. is there some tunnel which works? I am basically looking for a workaround here..

Comment: @JohnJ It's nearly 2017 and at this point there is absolutely no excuse for any web site anywhere on the planet to _not_ be on IPv6. Your first action in any such case should be to complain to the offending webmaster(s).

Answer (score -2):

Please update to python 3.6 and above.

ipv6 based urls are supported with python 3.6 and above

REST based URLs can be automated via requests library